# Não estou conseguindo pegar o valor do EditText da variável aux e comparar no if

Tags: java, android, edittext

Quando escreve 0 ou 1 do EditText é pra entrar no IF e não entra.

```
private TextView nome1;
    private TextView nome2;
    private EditText vitoria;
    private Button salvar;
    private TextView primeiroLugar;
    private TextView segundoLugar;
    private TextView terceiroLugar;

    int tamanho;
    Integer maiorValor = 0;
    int soma = 1;
    int k = 0;
    int j = 1;
    int m = 0;
    int n = 2;


    //CONTAGEM DOS PONTOS DE CADA JOGADOR
    //int cont = nomesAuxiliares.size();
    ArrayList<Integer> contador = new ArrayList<>();


    ArrayList<String> nomesAuxiliares = new ArrayList<>();

    public void compararNomes(int k, int j) {

        String aux1 = vitoria.getText().toString();
        //int num = Integer.parseInt(aux1);
        if(k != j || j > k) {

            if(k < nomesAuxiliares.size()) {

                if(j < nomesAuxiliares.size()) {

                    nome1.setText(nomesAuxiliares.get(k));
                    nome2.setText(nomesAuxiliares.get(j));


                    if(aux1.equals("0")) {

                        int cont = contador.get(k) + 1;
                        contador.remove(k);
                        contador.add(k, cont);
                        primeiroLugar.setText(String.valueOf(contador.get(k)));

                    }

                    else if(aux1.equals("1")) {

                        int cont2 = contador.get(j) + 1;
                        contador.remove(j);
                        contador.add(j, cont2);
                        primeiroLugar.setText(String.valueOf(contador.get(j)));

                    }


                }

            }

        }
        while(k == j || j < k) {

            j++;
            if(k != j || j > k) {

                if(k < nomesAuxiliares.size()) {

                    if(j < nomesAuxiliares.size()) {

                        nome1.setText(nomesAuxiliares.get(k));
                        nome2.setText(nomesAuxiliares.get(j));

                        if(aux1.equals("0")) {

                            int cont = contador.get(k) + 1;
                            contador.remove(k);
                            contador.add(k, cont);
                            primeiroLugar.setText(String.valueOf(contador.get(k)));

                        }
                        else if(aux1.equals("1")) {

                            int cont2 = contador.get(j) + 1;
                            contador.remove(j);
                            contador.add(j, cont2);
                            primeiroLugar.setText(String.valueOf(contador.get(j)));

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_terceira_tela);

        //listaAuxiliar = findViewById(R.id.IdListaAuxiliar);
        nome1 = findViewById(R.id.IdNome1);
        nome2 = findViewById(R.id.IdNome2);
        vitoria = findViewById(R.id.IdVitoria);
        salvar = findViewById(R.id.IdSalvar);
        primeiroLugar = findViewById(R.id.IdPrimeiro);
        segundoLugar = findViewById(R.id.IdSegundo);
        terceiroLugar = findViewById(R.id.IdTerceiro);


        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras != null) {

            nomesAuxiliares = extras.getStringArrayList("jogadores");

            ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    android.R.id.text1,
                    nomesAuxiliares
            );

            //listaAuxiliar.setAdapter(adaptador2);

        }


            for(int s = 0; s < nomesAuxiliares.size(); s++) {

                contador.add(s, 0);

            }

                if(j > k) {

                    nome1.setText(nomesAuxiliares.get(k));
                    nome2.setText(nomesAuxiliares.get(j));

                    String aux = vitoria.getText().toString();
                    int num = Integer.parseInt(aux);


                    if(num == 0) {

                        int cont = contador.get(k) + 1;
                        contador.remove(k);
                        contador.add(k, cont);
                        primeiroLugar.setText(String.valueOf(contador.get(k)));

                    }

                   else if(num == 1) {

                        int cont2 = contador.get(j) + 1;
                        contador.remove(j);
                        contador.add(j, cont2);
                        primeiroLugar.setText(String.valueOf(contador.get(j)));

                    }





                }
                else if(j <= k) {



                }


                k = 0;
                j = 2;
                //k = 0;
                //j = 1;
                //compararNomes(k, j);

        //TODOS CONTRA TODOS: logica como vai funcionar o jogo (vai aparecer na terceira tela)
        salvar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                vitoria.setText("");

                if(k == (nomesAuxiliares.size() - 1)) {

                    /*for(int m = 0; m < contador.size(); m++) {

                        if(contador.get(m) == null) {

                            //contador.add(m, 0);

                        }

                    }*/

                    for(Integer valor: contador) {

                        if(valor > maiorValor) {

                            maiorValor = valor;

                        }

                    }



                    //primeiroLugar.setText(String.valueOf(maiorValor));


                }

                compararNomes(k, j);

                j++;
                if(j == nomesAuxiliares.size()) {

                    k++;
                    j = k + ((j - j) + 1);
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá! Bem-vindo ao [SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Você precisa disponibilizar mais informações sobre seu problema, onde você tenta fazer isso e como. Faça isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/375756/edit)

Comment: Seria na parte da variavel AUX (pegando o valor do EditText) e depois comparar no IF para poder entrar dentro do laço.

Comment: if(aux1.equals("0")) {

                        int cont = contador.get(k) + 1;
                        contador.remove(k);
                        contador.add(k, cont);
                        primeiroLugar.setText(String.valueOf(contador.get(k)));

                    }

                    else if(aux1.equals("1")) {

                        int cont2 = contador.get(j) + 1;
                        contador.remove(j);
                        contador.add(j, cont2);
                        primeiroLugar.setText(String.valueOf(contador.get(j)));

                    }

Comment: Quando clica em 0 no editText e compara no IF não está entrando no laço.

Comment: Já fez debug? Já tentou transformar essa string que recebe no edittext pra inteiro? Se sim

Comment: Eu já fiz isso e dar erro o App

Comment: Qual erro que dá??

Comment: tentei transformar para inteiro: String aux = vitoria.getText().toString();
                    int num = Integer.parseInt(aux); Mas dar erro o App (fecha o App)

Comment: a parte que tem tem "if (num == 0)" e "else if (num == 1). Tá passando? pq eu acredito que o num é nulo.

Comment: Não está passando, eu coloquei assim String aux = vitoria.getText().toString();
                    int num = Integer.parseInt(aux); "if(num == 0) e else if(num == 1)", mas não entra no if quando o usuario escreve no EditText 0 ou 1

Comment: Eu encontrei possíveis 2 erros no código, vou tentar arrumar aqui e te mando o primeiro é que quando vc inicializa o layout o edittext é nulo, sendo assim você não consegue recuperar esse valor desse jeito, o outro erro que eu vi esta aqui:  vitoria.setText(""); Você anula o edittext e depois chama compararNomes, nunca vai cair na condição mesmo. Vou tentar arrumar aqui.

Comment: Ok, obrigada. Vou aguardar

Answer (score 0):

Embaixo do seu:

```
 for(int s = 0; s < nomesAuxiliares.size(); s++) {
        contador.add(s, 0);
    }
```

Coloque um Watcher pro seu edittext

```
    vitoria.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

 if(j > k) {

                    nome1.setText(nomesAuxiliares.get(k));
                    nome2.setText(nomesAuxiliares.get(j));

                    String aux = vitoria.getText().toString();
                     //Importante verificar se aux é nulo ou está vazio
        //se for nulo ou vazio num será 0
        int num = 0;
        if (aux != null && !aux.equals("")){
          num = Integer.parseInt(aux);
        }

        if(num == 0) {

            int cont = contador.get(k) + 1;
            contador.remove(k);
            contador.add(k, cont);
            primeiroLugar.setText(String.valueOf(contador.get(k)));

        }

        else if(num == 1) {

            int cont2 = contador.get(j) + 1;
            contador.remove(j);
            contador.add(j, cont2);
            primeiroLugar.setText(String.valueOf(contador.get(j)));

        }
                }
                else if(j <= k) {

                }
                k = 0;
                j = 2;
                //k = 0;
                //j = 1;
                //compararNomes(k, j);
        //TODOS CONTRA TODOS: logica como vai funcionar o jogo (vai aparecer na terceira tela)


        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
    });
```

E no Botão salvar deixe o vitoria.settext no final:

```
  salvar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (k == (nomesAuxiliares.size() - 1)) {

                /*for(int m = 0; m < contador.size(); m++) {

                    if(contador.get(m) == null) {

                        //contador.add(m, 0);

                    }

                }*/
                for (Integer valor : contador) {

                    if (valor > maiorValor) {

                        maiorValor = valor;

                    }
                }

                //primeiroLugar.setText(String.valueOf(maiorValor));
            }

            compararNomes(k, j);

            j++;
            if (j == nomesAuxiliares.size()) {

                k++;
                j = k + ((j - j) + 1);
            }

            vitoria.setText("");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Não consigo hoje analisar melhor o código, mas acho que assim está correto. Tudo que está em afterTextChanged é sempre atualizado quando o usuario altera o edittext

Comment: Ok, vou verificar agora. Obrigada

Comment: no seu método compararNomes pode também transformar a string aux em int :
    int num = 0;
        if (aux != null && !aux.equals("")){
          num = Integer.parseInt(aux);
        }

e nos if ao invés de usar aux, usa o num.

Comment: Ok, vou fazer isso. Obrigada

Comment: Deu certo o que eu tava querendo. Obrigada

Comment: Se a minha resposta solucionou o problema, por favor aceite-a como resposta, e se possível marque-a como útil. Obrigado e qualquer dúvida só falar.